# Infinitive of "мрут"

Tags: глаголы

Dose the infinitive form for "мрут" exist in Russian?

> Они **бегают** как лошади.   -- **бегать**
>
> Они **дерутся** как львы.    -- **драться**
>
> Они **мрут** как мухи.       --        ?

Comment: in modern usage **мрут** is a variant form of **умирают**, because it's  unique without separate counterparts for other persons and tenses and without an infinitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This from is [`мереть`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) but in modern Russian the infinitive form is virtually non-existent, my guess would be that some of native speakers will even fail to recognize that form.

Note that `мереть`, unlike `умирать` apart from dying has also other meaning, it's synonymous to "замирать" (to freeze).

Comment: Are you certain that мрёт can mean замирает? It seems far-fetched to me as a Russian speaker.